# Webscraping de imagens em comentarios

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Estou trabalhando em um *web scraper* que precisa resgatar comentários em um fórum que permite o *upload* de imagens. O texto e o autor do comentário consegui obter usando um `findAll` no Beautiful Soup, porém não consegui obter uma forma de salvar os links associados aos comentários (nem todos os comentários possuem imagens para obter um link)

No trecho de código tem como obtive os comentários e como tentei obter o link das imagens

```
title_comentou = container.findAll("div",{"class":"posting fullpost"})
comentario = title_comentou[0].text

title_imgem_link = container.findAll("div",{"img":"src"})
linkado = title_imgem_link[0].text
```

obtendo esse erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "2 - localBotBS4.py", line 54, in <module>
    linkado = title_imgem_link[0].text
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Parece que `title_imgem_link` não tem o valor que você espera ter. Já verificou qual é o valor dele?

Comment: Eu não entendo nada desse beautifulsoup, mas acho que o problema está na sua atribuição, você esta atribuído o valor retornado pelo método a uma variável simples e não para uma lista. Por isso ocorre esse erro: ```IndexError: list index out of range```. O correto seria:```title_comentou.append(container.findAll("div",{"class":"posting fullpost"}))```

Comment: Você já viu a [documentação do find_all](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all)? Quando você faz `container.findAll("div",{"img":"src"})` você está procurando por um `div` com o atributo `img` tendo o valor `src`, ou seja, você está procurando por `<div img="src">`... Suponho que não é isso que você quer...

Comment: sem ter a estrutura da página não tem como dizer muito